# Connecting RTK receiver to acquire cm precision on Z axis

Tags: qfield

I'm working with QField and I'm trying to connect an external RTK GNSS receiver, concretely the Polaris S100. This receiver works with NTRIP correction to acquire High precision measurement and the app that I used to manage it is Lefebure NTRIP Client and I have activated mock location on my mobile device and the elevation is Orthometric.

The promblem is: when I try to receive data with S100 connected to my Ntrip client, QField doesn't allow me, is says: `network error during read`. If I disconect Lefebure NTRIP APP the precision in X,Y, and Z goes above 1 m. I tried to switch off (always with Lefebure disconnected): `use orthometric altitud from dispositive` and on this occasion QField, connect for a few seconds and then disconnect. I am searching for any manual to correctly configure the app.

Comment: I know nothing about QField or Polaris S100, but I work with external GNSS a lot (mainly Trimble gear, also various SiRF and uBlox receivers.  How are you trying to connect to the receiver?  If you are using Bluetooth, it's likely that QField and NTRIP Client are trying to use the same port, only one can connect at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm trying to connect via Bluetoth. If it this the problem, how I could change the port? Lefebure works in 2100 port, but in Qfield I don't know where I can change it, or if I have to change on my android device. Best whises

Answer (score 2):

I had a look in the [S100 User Guide](https://www.polaris-gnss.com/S100_RTK_Receiver_User_Guide.pdf), assuming that's what you are using.

First of all, check that you do have the RTK license.   Paragraph 1-3 of the S100 User Guide says that without an RTK license you will not get RTK positions.

From the S100 User Guide guide, you should follow the steps in paragraph A-2-4 to set up Lefebure NTRIP Client app.  **I think that's what you have done already.**  Once you have set up corrections, leave Lefebure NTRIP Client app running - this is needed because you need to keep on feeding NTRIP corrections to the S100 the whole time you do your data collection in QField.

Now on to QField.
[This page in the QField manual](https://qfield.org/docs/fieldwork/gps.html) says "Make sure no other app like mock location providers are using the bluetooth antenna."
Looking at [QField User Guide](https://qfield.org/docs/prepare/gnss.html), because Lefebure NTRIP Client app is feeding positions to Mock Locations, you should use QField as if you are using the internal GPS / GNSS receiver.  Do not try to connect to the S100 as an external GNSS receiver.  I think this is the step you were getting wrong.

To confirm that positions in QField are coming from the S100 not from your phone's internal GPS / GNSS receiver, look at the precision values in QField.  When Position Type in Lefebure NTRIP Client app is RTK, precision should be at the centimeter level.